# Sketch layout to android XML

Tags: android, sketch-3

I have created a simple cardView in Sketch and I want to insert it inside the Android-Studio. What options do I have? Can I export it from sketch and import it to Android-Studio or I have to redesign it with XML or Java code? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make it as **PNG** and use it in your Android Project.

Or Make redesign it in **XML**.

Answer (score 0):

best option would be save this as svg from sketch and use in android studio
as svg is vector graphic and size can be handled in android studio